# Most standard way to have grid-based inputs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a standard way to create a dynamic grid-based form using ASP.NET MVC and Bootstrap? Users should be able to add and remove rows. I've done this in the past by having the controller action function guarantee there's at least one row in the model, then use JavaScript to copy the first row as a template and use regular expressions to change the indices of copies of that template before adding them into the row. Similarly, regular expressions are used to rewrite the index when a row is removed. That all seems inelegant to me.

"No, there is no standard way" is an acceptable answer if there isn't a standard way to do this. I'd rather not reinvent this wheel. I haven't had good luck with searches either on the web generally or here on Stack Overflow, so I apologize if this is a duplicate question.

edit: My motivation in asking is to do as many things as possible "the normal way". I think ASP.NET and the project templates that come with VS have come a long way, and there are a lot more "out of the box" ways of doing things than there were a few years ago. When I'm making a form, I want to make a form that meets stated requirements. My goal isn't to figure out the best way to make a form. There are several really good ways that have been figured out already. I can probably write two or three solutions to this problem as quickly as I can type, but I'd rather solve the problems that other .NET developers using the same solution. It's faster, likely requires less documentation and maintenance (especially if the framework provides most of the solution), and makes it easier to share the work with others.

[image]

Comment: No, there is no standard way

Comment: Is there a standard way that doesn't use Bootstrap?

Comment: You always can use any other ui framework. Jquery-ui, for ex

Comment: Is there a standard way using Jquery-ui? I'm trying to avoid reinventing wheels.